# "To have strong will" or "to be strong will"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

Which one is correct?

> People who are strong will

or

> People who have/has strong will

I was watching this movie and someone said:

People who are strong will, end up hurting others and people who are weak will, end up hating the others.

I wonder if it is correct or not.

Comment: I think it probable that you have either misheard or misparsed this utterance. There are two possibilities; the speaker may have said *People who are strong **will end up** hurting others* or may have said *People who are **strong-willed** end up hurting others*. Without hearing the actual soundtrack we cannot say which.

Comment: I think @StoneyB is correct and you've put in the commas by accident.

Comment: @StoneyB yes you are right, wrong commas :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either say

> People who have a strong will

or

> People who are strong-willed

These are both correct usages. In your case, however, it seems that you have put the commas in the wrong place, as mentioned by @StoneyB.